# XSLT select node without loosing attributes

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to do xslt transformation on xml tags and the output is coming as expected but all attribute value are getting trimmed off . I want to have all attributes need to be applied but specific attributes need to be modified like attribute names.

Please find below example.

```
<section>
  <line number='1' style='none' bold='true' size='10pt'>Line 1</line>
  <line number='2' bold='true' >Line 2</line>
  <line number='3' style='none' bold='true' size='10pt' color='red'>Line 3</line>
</section>
```

This i want to transform to

```
<div>
      <p num='1' style='none' bold='true' size='10pt'>Line 1</p>
      <p num='2' b='true' >Line 2</p>
      <p num='3' style='none' bold='true' size='10pt' color='red'>Line 3</p>
</div>
```

This is the example i have write so far. But is but complex because i cant assume which attribute applied so i don't want to give the names of attributes explicitly.

```
<xsl:template match="section"><div use-attribute-sets="default"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></div></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p"><p use-attribute-sets="default"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></p></xsl:template>

        <xsl:attribute-set name="default">
            <xsl:attribute name="number"><xsl:value-of select="@num"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:value-of select="@style"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="b"><xsl:value-of select="@bold"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="size"><xsl:value-of select="@size"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="color"><xsl:value-of select="@color"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Comment: You could apply-templates select="@*" on every applied node. Then you could do a match="@*" template with <xsl:copy/> and other specific match tamplates for specific attributes that do change like match="@bold". But I am not sure if you are searching for this since I did not completely understand your request.

Comment: Lets resolve 1st problem. I want all attributes to be applied as it is so i no need to mention attribute explicitly.Like one tag has 3 attributes and other tag has 5 attributes . I dont know what will be the name of those attributes but all attributes need to be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy all existing attributes by default with some exceptions you can achieve that like the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="*"> <!-- This matches all nodes. Note that specific templates have higher priority and will hit earlier (You can probably use your match="p" or "line") -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> <!-- Default value if no select is given is '*' so no attributes would be hit -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*"> <!-- Match all the attributes so you can copy them -->
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@bold"> <!-- Note that this will hit instead of @* because its more specific as described above -->
    <xsl:attribute name="b" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Here you can specify more of such attribute matches if needed -->
```

Comment: Wow now it working as expected i used the following work around with the example you have give.<xsl:template match="section"><div><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></div></xsl:template><xsl:template match="@*"> <!-- Match all the attributes so you can copy them -->
      <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: I am getting error at this line.<xsl:attribute name="class" select="."/>.It says "Illegal attribute 'select'"

Comment: <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute> This works for me now.

Comment: I did not test it in an editor, so there might be some syntax errors. But im glad you found your solution. :)

Comment: `*` does not match "all nodes" -- it only matches *elements*, and typically children [of the context node] at that.